# Updating product quantity (php and Mysql)

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update the product quantity in the basket.php page. The quantity would also be posted on MySQL database under coloumn **qty** in the **basket** table. But unfortunately it doesn't work as i had hoped.

**Problems:**

1. Updating quantity only works for one item in the basket.
2. After entering the quantity in the box say "3" and clicking the update_qty button, the value in the box is changed back to one. but the price is correctly updated.
3. Adding multiple items and updating their quantity will result in a wrong total price and the quantity of the last item is saved in the qty column for all items in the basket table.

**Database Structure:**

**Basket Table**

```
f_id type int(10) primary key//food id

ip_add type  varchar(225)

qty type int(10)//quantity in basket
```

**Food Table**

```
1   food_id type    int(100) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key

 2  food_cat type   int(100)            

3   food_type type  int(100)            

4   food_title type varchar(255)    

 5  food_price type float(23,2) 

6   food_desc type  text    

7   food_image type text    

8   food_keywords type  text
```

**Here is my code:**

**basket.php**

```
   session_start();
    include ("functions/functions.php");

    <form action = " " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Remove</th>
    <th>Dish(s)</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 

    $total = 0;

   global $con;

   $ip = getIp();

   $sel_price = "select * from basket where ip_add='$ip'";

   $run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price);

  while ($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)) {

  $foo_id = $p_price['f_id'];

  $foo_price = "select * from food where food_id ='$foo_id'";

  $run_foo_price = mysqli_query($con, $foo_price);

  while ($ff_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_foo_price)) {

    $food_price = array ($ff_price['food_price']);

    $food_title = $ff_price['food_title'];

    $food_image = $ff_price ['food_image'];

    $single_price = $ff_price['food_price'];

    $values = array_sum($food_price);

    $total += $values;
    ?>
    <?php 
  //updates quantity of items in basket
  if (isset($_POST['update_qty'])){

  $qty = $_POST['qty'];
  $update_qty = "update basket set qty='$qty'";
  $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);


  $total = $values*$qty;

  }
    ?>
<input type="number"  name="qty" value="<?php   echo $_SESSION['qty']; ?>" >


 <?php } } ?>


<b>Sub Total:</b>

 <?php echo "£". $total;?>

    <div id="up">
    <input type="submit" name="update_basket" value="Remove">
    </div>
    <div id="up">
    <input type="submit" name="update_qty" value="Update Quantity">
    </div>
     <div id="con">
     <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping">
    </div>
    <div id="chck">
     <a href="checkout.php"><button  type="hidden">Checkout</button></a>

    </div>
```

**functions.php**

```
      //Creates the basket
     function basket(){

     if (isset($_GET['add_basket'])){

      global $con;

    $ip = getIp();

    $foo_id = $_GET['add_basket'];

   $check_foo = "select * from basket where ip_add= '$ip' AND f_id =  
   '$foo_id'";

   $run_check = mysqli_query($con, $check_foo);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0){

   echo " ";
  }

 else {

 $insert_foo = "insert into basket (f_id,ip_add) values ('$foo_id', '$ip')";
 $run_foo = mysqli_query($con, $insert_foo);

  echo "<script>window.open('order.php','_self')</script>";
   }
 }

 }

   //Get total items in Basket
   function total_items(){

     if (isset ($_GET['add_basket'])){

      global $con;

      $ip = getIp();

      $get_items = "select * from basket where ip_add='$ip'";

      $run_items = mysqli_query($con, $get_items);

      $count_items = mysqli_num_rows($run_items);

      }

      else {

        global $con;

        $ip = getIp();

    $get_items = "select * from basket where ip_add='$ip'";

    $run_items = mysqli_query($con, $get_items);

    $count_items = mysqli_num_rows($run_items);

     }

    echo $count_items;
     }

  //get the total price of items in basket
 function total_price(){

  $total = 0;

   global $con;

  $ip = getIp();

  $sel_price = "select * from basket where ip_add='$ip'";

  $run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price);

    while ($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)) {

    $foo_id = $p_price['f_id'];

    $foo_price = "select * from food where food_id ='$foo_id'";

    $run_foo_price = mysqli_query($con, $foo_price);

    while ($ff_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_foo_price)) {

    $food_price = array ($ff_price['food_price']);

    $values = array_sum($food_price);

    $total += $values;

    }
   }

 echo "£" . $total;
    }
```

How can i change my code to solve these problems.

thanks.

Comment: there's some bad practice in here, don't use IP to identify people. One IP can be thousands of people, and any one can use many IP's

Comment: thanks, i would change that later on. at the moment i'm trying to get the core functions to work properly

Comment: identifying the appropriate cart\user is not core ?

Comment: never said it wasn't. i'm trying to fix everything one problem at a time

Answer (score 0):

@connor991, Your code is very clumsy. You need to rewrite your code. I'll suggest two ways.

But first of all you need to have a form where all items are displayed and the user selects an item to purchase. Then you redirect them to a place where you give more information and then they choose quality.

Then, first method: When displaying all items in the cart, you display them in separate `form` tags. This way, you have a `textbox` with current `qty` where the user can update if they wish to. You also provide a `submit` button to submit the form for update. This way, you can fetch individual `food_id`s and `qty`s and update accordingly.
I also realized that since one user `ip` can purchase more than one item, updating according to just `ip_add` will update all products under his/her `ip_add`. Therefore, you need to do this:

```
// Assuming that you have ip and food_id values already
UPDATE basket SET qty=$qty WHERE ip_add=$ip AND food_id=$food_id
```

Second option is to display all items in a table without providing `textbook` to update `qty` right away. You display an `update` link against each cart item so that when they click on it, you pass the food_id and ip_id of that particular cart item to a new page where you fetch the data from database and now display them plus the `qty` but with the `qty` in a `textbook`. When the user clicks on the update button on this page, you retrieve the values from this particular page and perform the update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the help. i've done what you said. update: (1) When i add two items into the basket and update the quantities say "6" and "6" for both items. in the qty column it is recorded as "3" for the first item and "6" for the second item. (2) the quantity in the number box on basket page changes back to 1 after updating and the subtotal for both items with updated quantities is wrong(Less than what its supposed to be)

Comment: i've also edited my question to include the database structure

Comment: @connor991, Before I update my answer, can you please explain this `<input type="number"  name="qty" value="<?php   echo $_SESSION['qty']; ?>" >`
I think you should remove the value you are setting and try again.

Comment: i have removed the value set, which removed the value in box after updating the quantity. (ie after selecting the quantity, the quantity in the box is erased). Also any quantity i enter in the basket is not posted to the qty column in the basket table.

Comment: i was trying to echo the quantity entered in a session, so if the user navigates to another page and returns to the basket the quantity set remains the same for that session.

Comment: Do you have a form tag? Because I can't find any form tag. How are you passing the values?

Comment: sorry about that. Yes i do, I have just updated the basket.php code. if you need the whole page let me know, i decided to leave some parts out becuase of huge headers, footers, search form etc

Comment: I have updated my answer. @connor991, try and post your results.

Comment: thanks, i'll try this as soon as possible. right now i am attending a lecture :)